# Android BLE: onDescriptorWrite, onCharacteristicWrite, onCharacteristicRead none are being called, but other callbacks work

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an Android client that connects to a custom BLE server (peripheral) using a custom service and characteristics.  I have verified that I can communicate with the device using the Android app BLE Scanner, and have also verified that I have correct UUIDs for the various characteristics.  I have written code to write to the write-only characteristic, and the onCharacteristicWrite callback is never called.  I have also written code to enable notifications on the read/notify characteristic, including updating the CCC descriptor to indicate notifications enabled, but neither the onDescriptorWrite, onCharacteristicWrite nor onCharacteristicChanged callback is called.  I know that the BluetoothGattCallback is properly registered, because I do get calls to onConnectionStateChanged and onServicesDiscovered.

This code enables notifications on a given characteristic:

```
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(CLASS_NAME, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    // Check if this characteristic actually has NOTIFY property
    if((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) == 0 ) {
        Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Characteristic does not support notifications");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    // For characteristics that support it, write to the CCC descriptor
    // that notifications are enabled.
    if (enabled) {
        if (TX_PERIPHERAL_TO_CENTRAL.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.TX_PERIPHERAL_TO_CENTRAL_CCC));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            if (!mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)) {
                Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Write to descriptor failed: "+TX_PERIPHERAL_TO_CENTRAL_CCC);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see in the logs that this gets called and that the writeDescriptor() call succeeds.  However, onDescriptorWrite is never called, neither is onCharacteristicChanged.

Here is the code for the callbacks:

```
        @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "in onCharacteristicChange() characteristic = "+characteristic.getUuid());
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "in onDescriptorWrite() status = "+status+", descriptor = "+descriptor.getUuid());
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "  descriptor value = "+descriptor.getValue());
    }
```

As you can see, I should be seeing something in the logs if either of these were called.

There's a similar issue with characteristic writes.  Here is the code that performs a write, but onCharacteristicWrite is never called after this:

```
    public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, String data) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(CLASS_NAME, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return false;
    }
    // Check if this characteristic actually has WRITE property
    if((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) == 0 ) {
        Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Characteristic is not writeable");
        return false;
    }
    byte[] ascii = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    if (characteristic.setValue(ascii)) {
        result = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this case, writeCharacteristic() always returns false, despite the fact that I check to make sure it's a writable characteristic.

I have also used BLE Scanner to make sure that the characteristics I'm using can successfully be written to and read using notifications, so whatever the problem is, it's on my end.  And apologies for the messy code - it's definitely in an incomplete state.

Comment: Where in the process is writeCharacteristic() returning false?  Your method parallels the method on BluetoothGatt, making your question ambiguous.  Have you added log statements to each if statement block to make sure the control flow is behaving how you would expect?

Comment: I've removed most of the comments to make the code easier to get through.  The value of result from writeCharacteristic() is logged by the caller.  It is always false.  I also know that the method is entered since I have a logging statement at the beginning of each method, allowing me to follow the flow.

Comment: Sorry - I meant "I've removed most of the logging", not comments!

Comment: You must not execute a gatt operation while another is pending. That's probably why writeCharacteristic returns false. Wait for callback of the previous operation to happen first.

Comment: I am calling them one at a time.  The test code I've built does nothing but call writeCharacteristic after the connection is made, so it is called when no other GATT operation is pending.  The same is true for the other operations.

Comment: Do you receive a callback in your BluetoothGattCallback before you initiate the next interaction with the remote device?  Also, are you logging every callback method in your BluetoothGattCallback?  You will at the least get a callback even if it's a disconnection.

Comment: Yes.  I receive a callback for connection status change, and can see that I have successfully connected.  (Or when the connection attempt fails.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out on my own.  The reason the attempts to write and turn on notifications were failing is the way in which I was managing the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` objects.  Using sample code I had found online, I was caching all of the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` objects that are returned from `BluetoothGatt.getServices()`.  I was then fetching each `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` from the cache and using it to make calls to operations such as `BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()` or `BluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification()`.  Apparently, this is not the correct approach.

I have since modified my code so that I fetch a fresh copy of the service and characteristic object from `BluetoothGatt` before making any of the calls that were failing, using the method shown here:

```
/**
 * Fetches a characteristic from the GATT server.
 * @param serviceUUID unique id of the service that has the characteristic
 * @param characteristicUUID unique id of the characteristic
 * @return the requested characteristic, or null
 */
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic getCharacteristic(UUID serviceUUID, UUID characteristicUUID) {
    if (characteristicUUID == null) {
        Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Attempt to fetch characteristic using null characteristic UUID");
        return null;
    }
    if (serviceUUID == null) {
        Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Attempt to fetch characteristic "+characteristicUUID+" using null service UUID");
        return null;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = null;
    BluetoothGattService service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(serviceUUID);
    if (service != null) {
        characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID);
        if (characteristic == null) {
            Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "getCharacteristic(): Unable to obtain characteristic.");
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "getCharacteristic(): Unable to obtain service.");
    }

    return characteristic;
}
```

With this, I now get the expected callbacks to `onCharacteristicWrite`, `onCharacteristicChange`, `onDescriptorWrite`, etc.  I hope this is helpful to someone in the future.